Which detective show had a killer that watched his victims lose hope?
This was an episode of an American detective or cop show from the late 90s or early 00s. The killer abducted people and held them for a long time, torturing them with photos and home movies of their families to make them lose all hope of seeing them again. Only when they had completely given up hope did he kill them.  His latest victim was a woman who refused to give up because she had a young child, I think a daughter?  The detectives are able to track him when they learn he works for a photo or video processing place and that's how he's learning about their families.  The killer has a backstory that involves when he was a young boy in the woods, he found a woman treading water in a well and watched her lose strength and drown instead of going for help.  
It is not Criminal Minds, Cold Case, or SVU.  It might be Crossing Jordan or Without A Trace but I can't find an episode description to match.  Thank you so much!

Sorry, I can't yet comment or else I would have asked why you excluded Cold Case. 
The reason is, that your description matches Episode "The Road" (Season 5, Episode 15) almost perfectly. If I remember correctly, his prior victim had had a daughter, but she didn't survive. His latest victim was rescued, she was hoping to meet her fiancee again (which she did). But apart from that, everything matches, especially the backstory (woman drowning in a well).
During the episode, Lilly and Scotty bring the killer to Philadelphia by car, hence the title.
Here are relevant links:
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1201289/?ref_=ttep_ep15
http://coldcase.wikia.com/wiki/The_Road

That's it!  That's the one!  I excluded Cold Case because I thought I had combed through every episode of it, but this one slipped by me somehow.  Thank you so much, this has been driving me crazy for years.

@NilbogIceCream If this the correct answer, you can mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the check mark next to the up/down arrows.
